# M2: issue with cron table with language translator

Tags: magento2, cron

I added a large number of CRON tasks to the translation table.
Now when I open this table I see an error:

**Manage Cron**

```
Warning: DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML(): Entity: line 1: parser error : CData section too big found in /home/shop/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Xhtml/Template.php on line 60
```

Any solution?

code file `template.php`

```
/**
     * Append
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return void
     */
    public function append($content)
    {
        $newFragment = $this->templateNode->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
        $newFragment->appendXML($content);
        $this->templateNode->appendChild($newFragment);
    }
```